# Do not want columns with null value in Proc Report

Tags: sas, proc-report

I am trying to create report like the one:

[image]

But I am getting the report like this:
[image]

I am using the proc report to do this. I don't want the columns which has All the values zero. The AFG,ALL,CapMkt,IIS and PWMDIv are the sublevels of CIB and CRE.

The code I used is:

```
    proc report data=CIB_PWM nowd;

column OWNER_NAME OWNER_EMP_NBR RM_Division RM_Region Owner_Team 
    Owner_YTD_Rev Owner_Prior_YTD_Rev Owner_Rolling_12_Rev  
Attd_Rpt_LOB,(Attd_Rpt_SubLOB, (N));

define Attd_Rpt_LOB / Across '   ' ;
define Attd_Rpt_SubLOB / Across '  ';
define N / ' ';
define OWNER_NAME / group 'OWNER_NAME' format=$488. /*missing order=formatted*/;
define OWNER_EMP_NBR / group 'OWNER_EMP_NBR' format=$80. missing order=formatted;
define RM_Division / group 'RM_Division' missing;
define RM_Region / group 'RM_Region' missing;
define Owner_Team / group 'OWNER_HO_MKT_DEPT' format=$324. missing order=formatted;
define Owner_YTD_Rev / analysis SUM 'Owner_YTD_Rev' format=DOLLAR15. missing;
define Owner_Prior_YTD_Rev / analysis SUM 'Owner_Prior_YTD_Rev' format=DOLLAR15. missing;
define Owner_Rolling_12_Rev / analysis SUM 'Owner_Rolling_12_Rev' format=DOLLAR15. missing;
run;
quit;
```

Do you think I need to add any more option for this one?

Your help will be very much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Shankar:

You probably figured something out by now.

The 'want' image shows columns with all zeroes, so it doesn't align with the statement "I don't want the columns which has All the values zero."

Perhaps you can post some sample data demonstrating the problem.

Without seeing more I would suggest creating one or more pre-report steps that look for sets of rows contributing to cases of 'not to be reported' and marking them with a exclude_flag.  The report step would then be able to use a statement

```
where not exclude_flag;
```

If this extra processing still does not produce the desired report, you may need to perform a data tranpose step and write a different Proc REPORT step.